# My WD Caviar Green SATA HDD cannot be detected

Tags: hard-drive

I have a WD 2TB Caviar Green SATA HDD. I used it as an external hard drive formatted to FAT32. The main purpose was to store my PS3 games. It worked fine and all of a sudden my PS3 stopped detecting it.

I tried connecting it to my pc and the same result. I took it off from the enclosure and plugged it directly to my PC and used the BIOS setup. The BIOS setup detects my HDD but it says it's 0.0MB!!!

I also tried the WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic tool and it wasn't much of use because the drive is not picking up by windows at all.

Is my HDD dead? Is it beyond repair?

Comment: PS3s encrypt drives when you first plug them in, at least internal drives. This could explain the 0.0MB free.

Comment: @ekaj yea it's true the even the full drive backups are encrypted and can't be read on a standard windows PC.

Comment: @meguroyama Windows still picks up FAT32 flash drives, so it may appear in Disk Management. obhasha, plug in the drive, go to the start bar and type disk management, and enter. Can you see the drive in the bottom part of the window? Also, how is the drive connected to the PS3? It's possible the connector went bad.

Comment: @ekaj ok if it were being used as a space expansion then yes I would say the drive is damaged / dead.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for all the answers. I used an enclosure to use the HDD as an external so it was connected to my PS3 via USB cable. I tried connecting the HDD to my PC with using the enclosure and using the internal SATA cables. But still windows is not picking it up. I can only see the HDD in BIOS. I never tried the disk management thing. I will try and get back to you guys. Any other insights?

Comment: If you get another one an don't really care about some Watt you should [disable IntelliPark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2eYyRI_F98) on WD Green HDDs. Depending on the usage this will extend the lifetime tremendously! I use them in a RAID where IntelliPark will kill your disk pretty fast.

Comment: @JakeGould Why did you protect this? It only has a single deleted answer. That's not a "long history" of deleted answers.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Because it was posted in 2013, no answer was ever chosen, and [the only comments to answers here indicates that the drive is dead because it’s clicking](https://superuser.com/a/694412/167207). I protected it because there is no way any answer can have value now and in my experience this will just result in “me too!” answers at best. Better protect it than have the extra headache of unwanted noise on this dead question.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for explaining, however we should give posters the benefit of the doubt, i.e. only *after* a question actually receives a significant number of bad answers should it be protected (unless it's a very active/controversial post in which case it may be necessary to protect more aggressively.)

Comment: Quote from the [SO blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/08/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/) upon which the [Protected Questions FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/271445) is based: *When in doubt, err on the side of letting new users prove themselves before locking them out.* This same guidance tells us we should protect questions when they're *attracting **a lot** of non-answers or very poor answers,* and that we should be *unprotecting* them when the abuse subsides unless they have "a long history" of bad answers. @Jake

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I would agree with you if this were a new post, but at 6+ years on this question is dead. My use of protecting is simply to ensure this question gets a quiet digital funeral.

Comment: @JakeGould I agree it needs a funeral and have VTC accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

- 1st: if you power it on you should hear the motor spinning, if not, it might be "dead".
- 2nd: if it's spinning, than you can change the sata cable
- 3rd: use a diagnostic software to check the HDD

PS: you can mound your HDD to other systems, this is helpful some times. The HDD might be recognized on other systems (newer or older)

[Bart's Stuff Test](http://www.nu2.nu/bst/)

[CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html)

[Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows](http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=810&sid=3&lang=en)

[**R-Studio**](http://www.r-studio.com/)

Comment: Hello Remus, I recently formatted my PC and I plugged in the HDD as an external using a USB enclosure. This time windows picks up the HDD and tries to install the device but then reports back as failed. And Yes, I can hear the drive spinning when I plug it in.

Comment: I don't know much about HDDs but I can hear come clicking noises from the HDD. Is that normal?

Comment: If you hear clicking noises, then it's time for a new one :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- go to `Computer Management > Disk Management`. You will see `disk <number>` labelled as unallocated.
- Right-click on it and choose New Simple Volume.
- click Next all the way or choose your own volume's name and size.

This should solve the problem. If not, try to change SATA cable.

Answer (score -1):

The MBR is probably corrupted on your HDD from it being in your ps3. They are two different systems and read and write data differently. Boot your pc with the HDD connected and start the OS repair disk. You will need to launch the command line in the OS setup screen. Follow the steps below:

Using a command line

```
Back up or move all data on the basic master boot record (MBR) disk you want to convert into a GUID partition table (GPT) disk. If the disk does not contain any partitions or volumes, skip to step 2.

For more information about backing up volumes, see Related Topics.

Open Command Prompt.

Type:

diskpart

If the disk does not contain any partitions or volumes, skip to step 7.

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

list volume

Make note of the number of the volume that you want to delete.

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

select volume n

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

delete volume

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

list disk

Make note of the disk number of the disk that you want to convert to a GUID partition table (GPT) disk.

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

select disk n

At the DISKPART prompt, type:

convert gpt
```

Comment: This looks like badly formatted copy from unknown source. "Related topics" are mentioned, but not part of the answer.